# Unable to install drivers after updating linux kernel 3.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

After updating to linux 3.10 my GPU stopped working, it is a EVGA NVIDIA geforce 650. So I went about to purge nvidia and reinstall, did not work. The first time I installed it worked the flawlessly. This is what happens, when i go to "Additional Drivers" > Activate > NVIDIA binary Xorgdriver, kernal, module and VDPAU library, I get the following error:

```
Sorry installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log`.
```

So I did the troubleshoot for that and still did not work.

Then, I went to the NVIDIA X Server Settings and got this error:

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run 'nvidia-xconfi' as root)`
```

I did that and I get the usual `New X config file written to 'etc/X11/xorg.conf`. That still does not work. I purged nVidia again. I downloaded it again via nVidia's website and booted to CMD to do a manual install, but when it won't boot to CMD it is just a black screen and nothing shows up.

I am new to Ubuntu so please go easy on me, I have a bunch of CS projects I have to finish for school so time is of the essence. (I don't know if this will help but I had issues installing JDK, it still does not compile correctly as well as RSA and SSH and GIT. so I don't know if I screwed up big time on the Kernel update).

Comment: Did you run `modprobe nvidia`?

Comment: No I didn't, I will try that out and report back,thank you for the reply!

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version? (12.04, 13.04, etc.) **32** or **64** bit?

Comment: Sorry i should have elaborated on that, it is 12.04 lts

Comment: *12.0lts 64 bit

Comment: I am not sure what the issue was,but I completely wiped all of nvidia off my HHD and installed everything on my SSD, worked first time around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the nvidia drivers are currently compatible with kernel 3.10. There are some patches floating around however I would wait for the official NVidia update. Go back to kernel 3.9 or earlier for the moment.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I did and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

**I had to fall back to my 3.9.3 kernel because of the same error in all of my 3.10.**

If you notice the error log:
   test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (     \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;

**Doing what it says to do was no help for me. The driver would not install. I've tried old drivers and beta. No luck.**

I checked in the /lib/modules//include/config and there was a missing file - autoconf.h and/or auto.conf

**If I were to guess, the new kernel broke it and nVidia hasn't produced a fix yet... or the other way around. If I figure out how to fix 3.10 + nvidia driver, I'll post here!**

***UPDATE:*** 
**Just to confirm, I am using the 3.9.11 Kernel and the nvidia 319.32 drivers installed perfectly. So apparently, the 3.10.x -does- have some issues that break the nvidia drivers.**